# Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string pdo php sql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know this question has  already been answered but i doesn't realy get the solution of my problem. I actualy try to select the numbers of salaries to a sql base but i have this error : "Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string"

Here is my code:

```
function getNbSalaries(){
   global $pdo;
   $query = "SELECT count(*) as nb FROM salaries ;";
   $prep= $pdo->prepare($query);
   $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $prep; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use either

```
->prepare()
->execute()
```

or

```
->query()
```

In this case as it is a query without any parameters this may well be the simplest solution

```
function getNbSalaries(){
   global $pdo;
   $query = "SELECT count(*) as nb FROM salaries";
   $prep= $pdo->query($query);
   $row = $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $row; 
}
```

It is not a good idea to use `global` like this, it would be a better idea to pass the connection as a parameter of the function like this

```
function getNbSalaries($pdo){
   $query = "SELECT count(*) as nb FROM salaries";
   $prep= $pdo->query($query);
   $row = $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $row; 
}

$row = getNbSalaries($pdo);
echo $row['nb']'
```

Comment: i see i do some modifications:

Answer (score 0):

that don't work but i see where is the problem i think:

my function :

```
function getNbSalaries($pdo){
 $query = "SELECT count(*) as nb FROM salaries ;";
 $prep= $pdo->prepare($query);
 $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $prep->execute();
 return $prep; 
}
```

and there is my code to return the result on my main page:

```
<p>Nombre de salariés : <?= getNbSalaries(); ?> </p>
```

Comment: i forgort the $pdo one my answer but he's on my code don't worry :)